# Trouble adding key-value pair into nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

Say I have:

```
info = {'2002': {'Spring': [{'month': 3}]}}
```

and I want:

```
info= {'2002': {'Spring': [{'month': 3}], 'Fall':[{'month':5}]}}
```

How do I update info? Whenever I try I keep on overwriting 'Spring' and end up with

```
 info = {'2002': {'Fall': [{'month': 5}]}}
```

I know the all of the nesting is very ugly-- unfortunately, it's necessary for what I'm working on.

Comment: What did you use to try and do this?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to create a new key inside '2002'. So what you want to do is this:

```
info['2002']['Fall'] = [{'month':5}]
```

Provided a dictionary as:

```
info = {'2002': {'Spring': [{'month': 3}]}}
```

Output with the above solution applied, provides:

```
{'2002': {'Fall': [{'month': 5}], 'Spring': [{'month': 3}]}}
```